# Deprecated posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, outdated-information

There are a lot of posts that are 'deprecated' (correct at that time, but not today).
E.g., [Google Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) v1 (not available these days).

The problem with these is that, many developers (especially newbies) may depend on those deprecated solutions, causing error and loss of time.

So, *my* opinion is, deleting those posts is not fair but, **flagging as deprecated** will be very helpful.

**Feature request: flagging → deprecated**

Comment: Or adding a comment that explains they are depracated? Or editing the post to add information about them being depracated and what the correct new way to do thing is? Which is more in line with the wiki aspect of all posts on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why? People will still see the posts and many will just ignore whatever such a flag means.

A better thing to do is:

Edit the post. Explain why the solution is old and deprecated and what the new and improved way is. This **improves** the post and makes it better for *everyone*, in particular in view of the existing links to it - no need for more clicking around to find the *actual* answer.

If you don't like the idea of editing a post by someone else, write a new answer detailing why the others are no longer correct and what the new hotness is. And comment on the old ones pointing to the new one.

Comment: Yup. That's better

Comment: For <2K users, wouldn't any such edit be rejected as an invalid edit or radical change?

Comment: Even more reasons to contribute wonderful content and get more than 2k @p.s.w.g. ;)

Comment: For the case at hand, writing a new answer is really the way to go. It's also more lucrative rep-wise!

Comment: @p.s.w.g - That's what the edit summary field exists for. And a good edit would explain the reason for the change in the body as well. Though, with robo-reviewers, that would probably not get through :(