# Making the 'Original Question' and 'Last Answered' dates easy to see instead of assuming duplicate, as tech evolves

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, search, outdated-information

There's a lot of talk about removing or penalizing questions because they are "duplicates", but there's a lot of times when a question should be reasonably reasked because the technology or subject has evolved over the years.

Examples:

- Phones (features, menus, etc.)
- Basically anything.

Making the original question and last answer dates an easily searchable would also potentially be super useful.

Comment: There's no real penalty - duplicate closures are meant to act as signposts, and a more up to date question with specific reference to a newer iteration of a technology ought not to be closed as a dupe to an older one

Comment: Hey notdan! What do you exactly mean by "making dates easy to see"? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The body of this question appears to have two distinct parts. The first part, on "outdated" duplicate questions, has been discussed to death (e.g. [here](/q/47584) and [here](/q/95011)). The second, on how to search for creation/activity date, is answered [here](/q/55037/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outdated Answers project kicking off on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361097/282094) https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200483/282094

Comment: Yes @Rob thank you. Also, for everyone who replied - I did not expect this much attention and feedback on my semi-ill thought out suggestion, but appreciate the awesome tenacity displayed for sure. Glad to be here.

Answer (score 3):

When you say:

> there's a lot of times when a question should be reasonably re-asked
> because the technology or subject has evolved over the years

I disagree because our wiki-style editing of questions and answers enables us to always improve a question and any one or more of its answers to keep the Q&A current with new software versions.

It may be that a question cannot be reasonably applied to a new version but, in that case you are not re-asking a question, instead you would be asking a new question.

To understand the style of answering that I am advocating and which is respectful of versions I think [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370651/215590) to [Version labels for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370640/version-labels-for-answers) is worth reviewing.  I think the most important thing for a software question and its answer(s) is to mention the version(s) they apply to.

Comment: Yep thats very true. I just found myself looking at very old posts the day I made this comment, and figured it might be worth looking at in a way that's maybe user-controllable or something. I obviously have little experience when it comes to running a site like this :)